# Flutter camera app to capture long receipt for OCR

Tags: flutter, ocr

Is there a plugin for Flutter that allows the inbuilt camera to capture long receipts for OCR?

Thanks.

My current code uses the default mobile camera to take snapshot of receipts that fit within the camera view, but struggles when the receipt is very long.